# Accessibility bar - Text To Speech - Vue website

Tags: vue.js, accessibility, text-to-speech

I am searching to add an accessibility bar to a website developed in Vue. I have found a great npm package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/accessibility, that does a lot of stuff and this is exactly what I was looking for but unfortunately their Text To Speech function supports only a few languages. I am interested in having a Text to Speech in Romanian and I see this package uses SpeechSynthesis WEB API and Romanian is not present.
Are you aware of any other npm package or any other solution (not for a commercial website) I could easily implement in order to let the user have the possibility to select any text on site that will be automatically read in Romanian?

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,
Marius

Comment: No shortcuts, you can use the html lang attribute for Romanian then code your templates correctly and you should be sorted, especially in Vue since it's added to html templates rather than taking them over like React or Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Except in some special cases, such buttons to launch text-to-speech on your site is probably totally useless.

The user who need such a function has most probably already an application on his/her system  that does what he/she need.
The user has already configured the application to fit his/her needs and preferences, i.e. language, voice, speed, etc.

For example, blind and partially sighted people use what is called a **screen reader**. Jaws, NVDA, VoiceOver and Talkback are four of them.
People with dys troubles have another range of specialized software that also use speech to help them with reading text. And so on.

The user has only to configure the software once for all, and then it is usable on all websites provided that they are effectively accessible according to WCAG standards.

ON the other hand, the button on your site launch text-to-speech with fixed parameters, which don't correspond to what the user want or expect.
Or, maybe, you provide a way to customize language, voice, speed, etc., but in any case the user has to make the configuration once more.
Imagine if you had to configure speech on every website, with as many different interfaces.

So, take more time making your site accessible on its own, rather than wasting time implementing such feature.

There is one case where a text-to-speech button can be interesting, though. If you are publishing articles of a certain length, it may be interesting to turn the article into a talking book that can be downloaded and then read disconnected.
However, even in this case, there are mobile apps that do it much better than what you can implement on a website. Look at Voice Dream Reader, for example.